# How can I modify java properties on the fly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, properties

I'm looking the way how to control java properties during installation procedure.

I'm have Spring Data JPA + Hibernate in my application. I've configured jpa properties in bean. And move it to property file.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show.sql}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

property file: prop-local-override.properties where local is environment variable.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl=update
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show.sql=true
```

So, everything works fine. But I want to change hibernate.hbm2ddl during installation process. I use rpm package for installation my app. For example, I want to set this property to "create" when app is installing. And return to update after each restart.

Looks like -Dhibernate.hbm2ddl=update works fine. But it's manual work. Does anyone has some idea how to make it automatically, without big tools like Puppet?

Thanks,
Sergii K.

Comment: What is wrong with 'update'? It creates the schema if it doesn't exist and, if it does exist, it will update it.

Comment: Actually nothing wrong. My database contains data which I use. This data automatically is inserting in hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files property. When I install my application, I want to have that data in database. But this property works only with create and create-drop values. So, I want dynamically modify it. And set "create" when install application and "update" when I restart or update it. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried changing this dynamically before, but you can access that property map from your entity manager:

entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties()

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Have you ever heart that Spring may understand different phases (install, update or remove). I know that rpm-maven-plugin contains targets: preinstallScriptlet and postinstallScriptlet. But he cannot get control under application, as I know.